# Margins won't work on divs, tables and other parrent elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my img's with margins trough div tag but it didn't work. So i then made table and tried that but still won't work. The only way it works is when i set margin to the img trough id.

```
<div id="games">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <h1>OUR GAMES</h1>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img id="crusader" src="stronghold-crusader-cover.jpg"></td>
                    <td><img id="dvojka" src="stronghold2-cover.jpg"></td>
                    <td><img id="warlords" src="stronghold-warlords-cover.jpg"> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>

td{
    margin: auto;
}
#crusader{
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px; 
}
#dvojka{
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
#warlords{
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: If the above code is the actual code you are using, you first have to learn how a proper HTML file is structered. Read this too [repro].

Comment: If something doesn't work, post that and not what does work. Furthermore, the posted markup is invalid, and margin doesn't work on table cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set a percentage as margin while the parent of your element have no size. It doesn't work because 5% of nothing is nothing.

```css
td{
    margin: auto;
    width:10%;
    height:10%;
}
#crusader{
    margin-top: 105%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px; 
}
#dvojka{
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
#warlords{
    margin-top: 14px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="games">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <h1>OUR GAMES</h1>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img id="crusader" src="stronghold-crusader-cover.jpg"></td>
                    <td><img id="dvojka" src="stronghold2-cover.jpg"></td>
                    <td><img id="warlords" src="stronghold-warlords-cover.jpg"> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
```

I have set one of the image to 105% just so the margin is obvious.
Notice that I put a margin size to the td, since the table is a block element, it takes full space so it have a size. When you set a size (even in percentage) to the td, you can set a margin in percentage to the imgs